# Directive to limit decimal numbers to 100.00 max in text input (Regex)

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript

I have a directive, which is limit text input to write only decimal numbers in the text input

Here is code of directive

```
 import { HostListener, Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    exportAs: 'decimal-number-directive',
    selector: 'decimal-number-directive, [decimal-number-directive]',
})
export class DecimalNumberDirective {
    private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$/g);
    private specialKeys: string[] = ['Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home'];
    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
    @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
    onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
        if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
            return;
        }

        const current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
        const next: string = current.concat(event.key);
        if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is input where I use it

```
<div class="col-2 pr-0">
                        <label>{{ l('Percent') }}</label>
                        <input
                            class="form-control"
                            type="text"
                            decimal-number-directive
                            name="percent"
                            [(ngModel)]="inquiryItemToAdd.percent"
                            maxlength="64"
                            (ngModelChange)="setTotalPrice()"
                            [readOnly]="!inquiryItemToAdd.servicePriceId || !servicePrice.isPriceCalculated"
                        />
                    </div>
```

But I can write for example 155.00 or 155.56. I need to limit it with 100.00 because I use this to write percents.

I tried to use this regex `private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^(\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?)|(100(\.0{1,2})?)$/g);` but I still can use 150 percents.

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Is it necessary for you to use regex?

Comment: yes, it necessary @AbuTaha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should match all positive numbers starting 0, 0.0, 0.00 to 100, 100.0, 100.00

**Regex**:

```
^(\d{1,2}|\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}|100\.[0]{1,2}|100)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/S9fbY7/3

---

**Update**:

you need to allow . to be typed beacuase `50.` is not a valid pattern but `50.8` is but every keystroke validates the whole regex, so you need to update your code bypass validation when `.` is pressed do nothing and then on blur if value ends with dot maybe remove the value or remove the dot or add 00 after the dot

Ignored Keys:

```
private specialKeys: string[] = ['Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', '.'];
```

On Blur you want to validate value ending with `.`. Note choose any one of the option based on your use case.

```
if (val.endsWith('.')) {
  // Option 1 strip the . (dot)
  this.el.nativeElement.value = val.substring(0, val.length - 1); 

  // Option 2 add 00 after the . (dot)
  this.el.nativeElement.value = val + '00'; 

  // Option 3 remove the value all together
  this.el.nativeElement.value = ''; 
}
```

---

**Final Code**:

```
import { HostListener, Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  exportAs: 'decimal-number-directive',
  selector: 'decimal-number-directive, [decimal-number-directive]',
})
export class DecimalNumberDirective {
  private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^(\d{1,2}|\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}|100\.[0]{1,2}|100)$/g);
  private specialKeys: string[] = ['Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', '.'];
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }
  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
      return;
    }

    const current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    const next: string = current.concat(event.key);
    if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  @HostListener('blur', [])
  onBlur(): void {
    const val = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    if (val.endsWith('.')) {
      this.el.nativeElement.value = val.substring(0, val.length - 1); // Option 1 strip the .
      // this.el.nativeElement.value = val + '00'; // Option 2 add 00 after the .
      // this.el.nativeElement.value = ''; // Option 3 remove the value all together
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it not allow me type `.`

Comment: and I cannot type 100

Comment: Here is how it looks like now `private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^(\d{1,2}|\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}|100\.[0]{1,2}|100)$/g);`

Comment: you need to allow . to be typed beacuase `50.` is not a valid pattern but `50.8` is but every key stroke mesures the whole regex, so you need to update your code when . pressed do nothing and on blur if value ends with dot maybe remove the value or remove the dot

Comment: How I can do this?

Comment: Because in my variant I can type .

Comment: Yes you need to bypass . and validate on blur. Check updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Try out the following regex .

> ^ :- it will check that always the string starting with 100 
>   [0]{2} :- it will check the after `.` there must be 2 zeros only.

```
private regex: RegExp = /^100\.[0]{2}/gm;
```

You can check the [result](https://regex101.com/r/AlQhJu/1) in this .

Comment: You have to escape the dot to match it literally or else `100X00` will also match. You can omit the character class and just use 0. Note that this will only match strings that start with 100.00.

Comment: I cannot type anything in input with this regex

Answer (score 0):

I guess this pattern will work:
^(\d{0,2}(.\d{1,2})?|100(.00?)?)$

Comment: I can type 92309 and cannot type decimals

Here is how it looks `private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^(\d{0,2}(.\d{1,2})?|100(.00?)?)$/g);`

Comment: Please try this: ^(\d{0,2}(\.\d+)?|100(\.0+)?)$

Comment: Now I cannot type `.`

Here is how it's looks like `private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^(\d{0,2}(\.\d+)?|100(\.0+)?)$/g);`

Comment: I have tested it, it will work,
^(100(?:\.00?)?|\d?\d(?:\.\d\d?)?)$